# Regex for digits in Unix find command

Tags: regex, unix, command-line, find

I have this command:

```
find reports/ -type f -mtime +90 -regex ".*\.\(csv\|sql\|txt\|xls\|zip\)"
```

And I need to beef it up so the part before the file extensions matches a `YYYY/MM/DD` pattern, like so:

```
reports/2010/10/10/23.txt
reports/2010/10/10/23.xls
reports/2010/10/10/26.csv
reports/2010/10/10/26.sql
reports/2010/10/10/26.txt
reports/2010/10/10/26.xls
reports/2010/10/10/27.csv
```

But I'm failing to get any permutation of `\d` and parens escaping to work.

*UPDATE*: here's what worked for me based on the accepted answer below:

```
find reports/ -type f -mtime +90 -regex "reports/201[01]/\([1-9]\|1[012]\)/\([1-9]\|[12][0-9]\|3[01]\)/.*\.\(csv\|sql\|txt\|xls\|zip\)"
```

Comment: Note that -regex option is not standard across Unix platforms.  I think it may only be on GNU find.  You can do a more standard method by piping the output to egrep.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I have used in the past:

```
Year: (19|20)[0-9][0-9]
Month:  0[1-9]|1[012]
Day: (0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

You can put these together in your regex. You will, ofcourse, have to escape the brackets and pipes.

Answer (score 7):

`\d` is an extension of regular expressions that is not supported by Emacs regular expressions and POSIX regular expressions (those are the flavours `find` supports). You can use `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]` instead.

Comment: You can use `[0-9]`, but if you can use `[[:digit:]]` depends on which `-regextype` you use. For example `emacs` (the default type) does not support it whereas `posix-extended` does. See [GNU findutils manual: 8.5 Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html) for the syntax descriptions linked on the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

The following is ugly and does not weed out invalid dates, but might be close enough:

```
find reports/ -type f -regex ".*/reports/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]\.\(csv\|sql\|txt\|xls\|zip\)"
```

Comment: That looks good (and I'll test it in a bit) but is it possible to tighten up the ranges with something like "[0-9]{4}" instead of repeating it four times in a row?

Comment: The numeric quantifier "{4}" did not seem to work with the version of `regexec` in the version of `libc` used by `find` on my system (libc 2.3.4).  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the repeaters like this:

```
find ./ -regextype posix-egrep -iregex ".*\._[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{6}.*"
```

I use this to find backups of the form:

```
./foo._20140716-121745.OLD
```

Where `foo` is the original name and the numbers are the date and time.

(on CentOS 6.5)

P.S. `-regextype posix-extended` works too.